# Understanding the orientation of USB 3.0 superspeed TX/RX lines and when to flip the lines

Tags: pcb, usb, high-speed, usb-hub

I'm working on a device that will have an onboard storage device with a USB interface, as well as two USB 3.0 type-A connectors (a plug and a socket), along with a USB hub ic. I'm using the [Microchip 5744](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/USB5744#document-table) hub controller chip and I was confused about how I will actually need to hook up this chip because there are three different "configurations" on my board for how I will need to hook things up, and I'm confused on the standard for where the TX RX flip happens in USB 3.0.

1. The first configuration is the upstream USB-A plug connector that will plug into the main computer. The data sheet for the USB5744 hub chip says that I should connect the TX and RX pins on the IC to the "upstream superspeed transmit/receive plus/minus". For my case though, does this mean that I should connect the "upstream TX port" pin of the IC hub directly to the TX port of the USB A plug connector on my board? This is a direct plug application so according to this [application note](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/How-is-the-USB-TX-RX-connected) from microchip, it needs to be swapped somewhere. I wasn't sure if the upstream port referred to the connector on my board or the other connector that it would be plugged into. It looks like, in a direct plug, the pins on the port and socket both labeled TX are directly connected to each other. My overall confusion is where the swap needs to happen and what perspective I should look at this from.
2. The other configuration is my onboard SATA-USB chip which will be one of the downstream USB devices of the hub. The datasheet for the hub ic lists the pins as "downstream ports tx/rx +/-". So, if I have a chip directly on the board that needs to connect to the hub, should I connect the downstream's sata-usb IC RX pin to the pin labeled "downstream port RX" or does it need the "downstream port TX" since the hub might be expecting a USB connector that would then flip the lines?
3. Last one is the USB-A socket on my board, for the USB hub "downstream port RX", should this be the pin labeled as the "ssRX +/-" on the socket itself?